# Debug Output from directx(x-64) control panel

Tags: visual-studio, directx, windbg

How to Capture DirectX 10/11 debug output to Visual Studio or windbg?

Windbg is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this post would be useful? http://blog.rthand.com/post/2010/10/25/Capture-DirectX-1011-debug-output-to-Visual-Studio.aspx